# creating line breaks based on regex in R

Tags: r, split, lines

I am new to R.  I have extracted some text from web and pasted in a text file.  They look like this.

```
    c("HR name as meena in malad west branch first source ltd called me for interview as openings in llyods chat process as banking process she told me 3 rounds of interview and other hr vl ask me these questions.As she said there r openings but when other hr taken my interview she told there r no...", 
"", "", "Sir with due respect from 7 nov 2015, i dont receive my sms alerts from my registered mobile number as 9596159288 . ", 
"Account name Tariq Ahmad Mir", "Branch: WATRIGAM", "Contact: 1954-235307", 
"", "IFSC Code: SBIN0004591 ", "", "", "MICR Code: 193002321..."
```

Each of these comment is separated by "..." at the end of the comment.  I was trying to concatenate each comment into one single line.  I tried the following code:

```
a <- readLines("banking1.txt", warn = FALSE)
a <- a[sapply(a, nchar) > 0]
a <- paste(a, collapse = ",")
```

which gave me an output as follows:

```
"HR name as meena in malad west branch first source ltd called me for interview as openings in llyods chat process as banking process she told me 3 rounds of interview and other hr vl ask me these questions.As she said there r openings but when other hr taken my interview she told there r no...,Sir with due respect from 7 nov 2015, i dont receive my sms alerts from my registered mobile number as 9596159288 . ,Account name Tariq Ahmad Mir,Branch: WATRIGAM,Contact: 1954-235307,IFSC Code: SBIN0004591 ,MICR Code: 193002321..."
```

I am trying to split them using the ... delimiter.

```
a <- strsplit(a, "...,")
a <- strsplit(a, "...,")[[1]]
a <- noquote(strsplit(a, "...,")[[1]])
```

and many other similar options.  But the output is not what I expect. What I need is

```
HR name as meena in malad west branch first source ltd called me for interview as openings in llyods chat process as banking process she told me 3 rounds of interview and other hr vl ask me these questions.As she said there r openings but when other hr taken my interview she told there r no...
Sir with due respect from 7 nov 2015, i dont receive my sms alerts from my registered mobile number as 9512139288 . Account name Tariq Ahmad Mir Branch: MAGRITAW Contact: 1954-235307 IFSC Code: AVCN0001234 MICR Code: 19300321...
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a negative lookbehind.

```
x <- c("HR name as meena in malad west branch first source ltd called me for interview as openings in llyods chat process as banking process she told me 3 rounds of interview and other hr vl ask me these questions.As she said there r openings but when other hr taken my interview she told there r no...", 
  "", "", "Sir with due respect from 7 nov 2015, i dont receive my sms alerts from my registered mobile number as 9596159288 . ", 
  "Account name Tariq Ahmad Mir", "Branch: WATRIGAM", "Contact: 1954-235307", 
  "", "IFSC Code: SBIN0004591 ", "", "", "MICR Code: 193002321...")
y <- paste(x, collapse="\n")
z <- gsub("(?<!\\.{3})\\n+", " ", y, perl=TRUE) 
z <- strsplit(z, "\n")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dN7mC8/1)

Comment: My apologies Avinash Raj....you code helps...but I just realised i pasted the formatted output, and when I apply your solution....It was not working....I have corrected the example data now....could you pls help?

Comment: Many thanks Avinash Raj.  You code helped a lot.  But since using `cat` I couldn't store the output to a variable...just made some tweaks to suit my case. `z <- gsub("(?<!\\.{3})\\n+", " ", y, perl=TRUE)`
`z <- strsplit(z, "\n")` Many thanks again.